# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.. How to fix?

Tags: php, properties

Here is the Code, from where error is coming :)
I hope that I'll get my answer quick!!!

```
function getSubs($id, $type, $start = null) {

        if($type == 0) {
            if(is_numeric($start)) {
                if($start == 0) {
                    $start = '';
                } else {
                    $start = 'AND `relations`.`id` < \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($start).'\'';
                }
                $limit = 'LIMIT '.($this->s_per_page + 1);
            }
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `relations`, `wp_users` WHERE `relations`.`subscriber` = '%s' AND `relations`.`leader` = `wp_users`.`ID` $start ORDER BY `relations`.`id` DESC $limit", $this->db->real_escape_string($id));
        } else {
            if(is_numeric($start)) {
                if($start == 0) {
                    $start = '';
                } else {
                    $start = 'AND `relations`.`id` < \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($start).'\'';
                }
                $limit = 'LIMIT '.($this->s_per_page + 1);
            }
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `relations`, `wp_users` WHERE `relations`.`leader` = '%s' AND `relations`.`subscriber` = `wp_users`.`ID` $start ORDER BY `relations`.`id` DESC $limit", $this->db->real_escape_string($id));
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $array [] = $row;
        }
        return array($array, $total = $result->num_rows);
    }

    function getActions($id, $likes = null, $type = null) {
        global $LNG;


        if($type == 1) {
            $verify = $this->verifyLike($id);
            $result = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `messages`, `wp_users` WHERE `id` = '%s' AND `messages`.`uid` = `wp_users`.`ID`", $this->db->real_escape_string($id)));
            if($result->num_rows == 0) {
                return $LNG['like_message_not_exist'];
            }
            if(!$verify) {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `likes` (`post`, `by`) VALUES ('{$this->db->real_escape_string($id)}', '{$this->db->real_escape_string($this->id)}')");
                $stmt->execute();
                $affected = $stmt->affected_rows;
                $stmt->close();
                if($affected) {
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE `messages` SET `likes` = `likes` + 1, `time` = `time` WHERE id = '{$this->db->real_escape_string($id)}'");
                    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    $insertNotification = $this->db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO `notifications` (`from`, `to`, `parent`, `type`, `read`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '2', '0')", $this->db->real_escape_string($this->id), $user['uid'], $user['id']));
                    if($this->email_like) {
                        if($user['email_like'] && ($this->id !== $user['ID'])) {
                            sendMail($user['user_email'], sprintf($LNG['ttl_like_email'], $this->username), sprintf($LNG['like_email'], realName($user['user_login'], $user['first_name'], $user['last_name']), $this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$this->username, $this->username, $this->url.'/index.php?a=post&m='.$id, $this->title, $this->url.'/index.php?a=settings&b=notifications'), $this->email);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $x = 'already_liked';
            }
        } elseif($type == 2) {
            $verify = $this->verifyLike($id);
            $result = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `id` FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = '%s'", $this->db->real_escape_string($id)));
            if($result->num_rows == 0) {
                return $LNG['like_message_not_exist'];
            }
            if($verify) {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `likes` WHERE `post` = '{$this->db->real_escape_string($id)}' AND `by` = '{$this->db->real_escape_string($this->id)}'");
                $stmt->execute();
                $affected = $stmt->affected_rows;
                $stmt->close();
                if($affected) {
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE `messages` SET `likes` = `likes` - 1, `time` = `time` WHERE id = '{$this->db->real_escape_string($id)}'");
                    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `notifications` WHERE `parent` = '{$this->db->real_escape_string($id)}' AND `type` = '2' AND `from` = '{$this->db->real_escape_string($this->id)}'");
                }
            } else {
                $x = 'already_disliked';
            }
        }
    if($likes == null) {
            $query = sprintf("SELECT `likes` FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = '%s'", $this->db->real_escape_string($id));
            $result = $this->db->query($query);
            $get = $result->fetch_row();
            $likes = $get[0];
        }
        $verify = $this->verifyLike($id);
        if($verify) {
            $state = $LNG['dislike'];
            $y = 2;
        } else {
            $state = $LNG['like'];
            $y = 1;
        }
    if($this->l_per_post) {
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `likes`,`wp_users` WHERE `post` = '%s' and `likes`.`by` = `wp_users`.`ID` ORDER BY `likes`.`id` DESC LIMIT %s", $this->db->real_escape_string($id), $this->db->real_escape_string($this->l_per_post));

            $result = $this->db->query($query);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            $people = '';
            foreach($array as $row) {
                $people .= '<a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$row['user_login'].'"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$row['image'].'&w=25&h=25&t=a" title="'.realName($row['user_login'], $row['first_name'], $row['last_name']).' '.$LNG['liked_this'].'" /></a> ';
            }
        }
$actions = '<a onclick="doLike('.$id.', '.$y.')" id="doLike'.$id.'">'.$state.'</a> - <a onclick="focus_form('.$id.')">'.$LNG['comment'].'</a> - <a onclick="share('.$id.')">'.$LNG['share'].'</a> <div class="like_btn" id="like_btn'.$id.'"> '.$people.$likes.'</div>';

        if(empty($this->id)) {
            $actions = '<a href="'.$this->url.'">'.$LNG['login_to_lcs'].'</a> <div class="like_btn"> '.$people.$likes.'</div>';
        }
        if(isset($x)) {
            return $LNG["$x"].' <div class="like_btn"> '.$likes.'</div>';
        }
        return $actions;
    }
```

Comment: You expect someone to run this just to help you? Elaborate your question. Whats the problem you are having?

Comment: *"I hope that I'll get my answer quick!!!"* - **Quick** is for fast food and I'm not much of McDoggy fan myself.

Comment: At least post the full error message.

Comment: did you really think that people have been waiting for you to sign up....so they can jump to it to see how fast you get answer? Dumb comments like `answer quick` will kill you around here. People will help if you put more effort into asking questions that outline exactly what your issue is , and are respectful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notice "Trying to get property of non-object" couldn't be more clear. You are trying to read a property of something that is not an object.

For example:

```
$object = false;
echo $object->property; // Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Probably it is happening because you are assuming every SQL query you are doing is succeeding. But if a SQL query has errors and fails to run, the call returns `false` instead of a results object.

Sinse you didn't even say what line you are having this problem it's not worth the effort of helping you any further here. Check if your queries are suceeding before trying to use the result and read the MySQL error message from `$this->db->error` to figure out whats going wrong.